# Windows PowerShell - How to view commands history date/time

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, history

I want to list entered commands in Windows `PowerShell` with their respective timestamps. How can I do it with `Get-History` command?

Also if that isn't doable then please show me a way to check which `urls(network)` at which timestamps have been accessed through the `CMD`.

**Also consider that I've restarted my computer.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882382/powershell-track-history-as-full-objects-across-sessions

Answer (score 23):

On Windows 10, the PS extension PsReadline comes with PowerShell 5 by default. Get-Content on the following to view your full command history.

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt

To make it available on Windows 7,  you have to make sure you have the latest Framework and PowerShell 5 installed.  Then you can install the PsReadline module.

I just did on a Windows 7 (64) machine:

(executionpolicy : remotesigned)

**Install-Module PSReadLine** ( I was asked to install NuGet-anycpu.exe, and answered yes).

**Import-Module PsReadLine**

Your history will now be stored in the file mentionned above (verified)

Run **Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler**  to have a list of PSReadline Key bindings.

Comment: The directory `C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell` does not exist for me ...

Comment: True if you're running earlier versions of PS.   Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hmm. I'm running version 5.0 - what version are you running?

Comment: Looks like there is no `PSReadline` in the Windows 7 implementation of PowewrShell 5.0.

Comment: You are absolutely right David,  sorry for the misleading.  Post edited.

Comment: Installed. Great! +1. Now I need to figure out how to fix the colors it broke! :)

Comment: Thanks!  You can use Get-PSReadlineOption to see the default options/colors and then use SET-PSReadlineOption,  I'll try that now. please let me know about the colors it broke

Comment: Fixed :) I have a white BG and the keyword colour was set to Yellow - unreadable :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46646/discussion-between-dan-st-g-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 11):

The Powershell history is saved in the file ConsoleHost_history.txt to find the location of the file execute this PS command:
`(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, once you close a PowerShell console all history and logs are disposed.

You could check out something like: [Giving PowerShell a Persistent History of Commands](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/06/17/giving-powershell-a-persistent-history-of-commands)

Of course this won't retrieve anything you've already done, it will only start logging from the point you install it.

EDIT: PowerShell 5.0 appears to have implemented a persistent history, available even after restart, accessible via the usual ways.

Answer (score 2):

For PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core, I've added this to my `$PROFILE` to make it a little easier to remember:

```
function Get-PSReadLineHistory
{
    Get-Content (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Get-History | Select StartExecutionTime,ID,CommandLine

Comment: This only works for the current shell session. OP had restarted his computer.